# Creating DB triggers through JPA / Hibernate in Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

As the title says I want to create triggers to create records in other tables when data is added in the primary table. For example, when a user registers, I want records in user_friends with some default value.

Initially I thought to handle in the service layer like this.

```
repositoryA.save(entityA);
repositoryB.save(entityA);
```

But this method creates two different db sessions and I want to keep the number of sessions / calls to a minimum. Would also like to avoid native SQL or tweaking the db directly.

Comment: If this code is in a single service method with `@Transactional` it is a single session. If you want default values, then make a proper mapping in JPA and fill the defaults in your java code.

Comment: Wow. This is quite the revelation to me.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a relation between the tables you can persist the data in one save action.
See also [JPA Persist parent and child with one to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197947/jpa-persist-parent-and-child-with-one-to-many-relationship)

Comment: Interesting. In my case the mapping/relationship is owned by the child. I tried to avoid having cascades but I'll reconsider. This + using @Transactional might solve my issue.