# Hibernate @OneToMany - child owns the relationship, but only has the parents id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

I have a @OneToMany relationship defined on the parent class like so:

```
public class Course {
  @OneToMany(
      mappedBy = "courseId",
      fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
      cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
      orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<Student> students;
}
```

On the other side of the relationship, I simply keep the id of the parent entity:

```
public class Student {
  private Long courseId;
}
```

When I **save** a Course with new Students, hibernate first persists the Course, and then tries to persist each Student which is what I would expect.  (I can see this via hibernate logging.)

However, when it goes to insert each Student, it is passing a `null` for the `courseId`.  The database ends up throwing this error:
`ERROR: null value in column "courseid" violates not-null constraint`
 I have other examples of this working correctly in the code, but for some reason this one is behaving differently.

Is there a reason it's not using the id from the Course it just saved?  Is there some other configuration I need to add to support this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35198173/1123532

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your `Student` class:

```java
public class Student {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="course_id", nullable=false)
    private Course course;
}
```