# Why does Spring Boot hibernate OneToMany mapping child returns null values?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I recently started working with *Spring Boot* and *Hibernate*. I just tried to implement my first mapping between two entities.

But I don't really understand how the different mapping annotation works. I'm getting `null` values when I try to persist an Entity into my database.

I've an `Institution` Entity that can contain many `Department` Entities (OneToMany), and a `Department` Entity that relates to one `Institution` Entity (ManyToOne).

This is my Institution Entity

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Table(name = "institution")
public class Institution {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "acronym")
    private String acronym;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "institution")
    List<Department> departments;
}
```

Department Entity

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "institution_id")
    private Institution institution;
}
```

InstitutionService

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class InstitutionService {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InstitutionService.class);
    private final InfoMessages infoMessages = new InfoMessages();

    private final InstitutionRepository institutionRepository;

    public Institution addInstitution(Institution institution) {
        return institutionRepository.save(institution);
    }

    public Optional<Institution> getInstitutionById(UUID id) {
        return institutionRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public List<Institution> getInstitutions(String searchParam) {

        if (searchParam != null) {

            return institutionRepository.findInstitutionByAcronymContainingOrNameContainingIgnoreCase(searchParam, searchParam);
        }

        return institutionRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Institution getInstitutionByName(String name){
        return institutionRepository.findInstitutionByName(name);
    }
}
```

InstitutionController

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Api(value = "/institution", tags = "Institution Management System")
@RequestMapping(
    path = "/institution",
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@RestController
public class InstitutionController {

    private final InstitutionService institutionService;

     @ApiOperation("Add institution")
    @PostMapping(consumes = ("application/json"))
    public ResponseEntity<WrappedResponse<Institution>> createInstitution(
        @ApiParam("JSON Object representing Institution")
        @RequestBody Institution institution
    ) {

        institutionService.addInstitution(institution);

        WrappedResponse<Institution> wrappedResponse = new WrappedResponse<>();
        wrappedResponse.setList(Collections.singletonList(institution));

        return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
            .location(URI.create("/institution/" + institution.getId()))
            .body(
                wrappedResponse
            );
    }

}
```

This is my input

```
{
  "acronym": "uio",
  "departments": [
    {
      "name": "Biology"
    }
  ],
  "name": "University of Oslo"
}
```

This is the JSON Payload returned when I try to post an Institution Entity

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "id": "2163ff6a-71f4-40f7-bec2-dfeadbcdfec8",
      "name": "University of Oslo",
      "acronym": "uio",
      "departments": [
        {
          "id": null,
          "name": "Biology",
          "institution": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Why am I getting `null` values for Department ID and Institution ID ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why am I getting null values for Department ID

Because you have not specified any cascade on the OneToMany. So persisting an Institution does just that: persisting the institution. If you also want to persist the depertments it contains, the PERSIST operation (at least) needs [to be cascaded](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#cascade--). Since the department is not persisted, no ID is being generated for it.

> Why am I getting null values for Institution ID

Because the `institution` field of the department you're saving is null. 
So it's also null in the JSON. And even with a proper cascade, you would still get a null `department.institution_id` in the database. You need to add code to initialize this side of the association, which doesn't exist in the input JSON.

Note however that, if it was not null, since you're trying to serialize as JSON a cyclic data structure, you would get a stack overflow error. I strongly advise not to accept and return JPA entities in the controllers. Those represent the persistent state of your app. Design your API be clearly specifying what JSON you want to receive and return, and design classes representing that JSON. A JSON document is a tree. It can't be a cyclic data structure.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean with 'You need to add code to initialize this side of the association'. We added the proper cascade type (PERSIST ) and it fixed the departmentID issue (Thanks!)

Comment: `institution.getDepartments().forEach(d -> d.setInstitution(institution));`

Comment: Thank you! :D unfortunately that line creates an infinite recursion. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Yes. It's written in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for my issue in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177191/spring-mvc-rest-jpa-hibernate-jackson-infinite-recursion-one-to-many-json-error)

apperently I had some issues with Jackson and how it mapped the JSON object to my entities.