# getParameter() is returning null value with post method

Tags: java, jsp

I have done a lot of cross referencing on this but I don't understand where am I going wrong. I'm using this code while uploading a file. I could upload a file successfully but `getParameter()` is returning null all the time.

HTML code:

```
 <form action="uploadingservlet" method="post"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="propername" >
  <input type="file" name="file"  >
   <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
  </form>
```

Servlet code:

```
    public class uploadingservlet extends HttpServlet{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
           HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException,IOException {

   isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
   fname=request.getParameter("propername");
...
```

Comment: is the servlet annotated with @MultipartConfig  ??

Comment: no I am importing  org.apache.commons.. package

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937841/multipart-form-data-does-not-support-for-request-getparamerter

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

Answer (score 1):

request.getParameter() doesn't support multi-part requests. It always returns null. You need to use [FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html). 
Also look at http://javakart.blogspot.in/2012/11/file-upload-example-using-servlet.html http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm

Comment: does not look like so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet