# Empty List<MultipartFile> when trying to upload many files in Spring with ng-file-upload

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, ng-file-upload

I have the following controller method for uploading multiple files at once, inspired by [this blog post](http://crunchify.com/spring-mvc-tutorial-how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-specific-location/) and answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017807/spring-3-upload-many-files) as well:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{user}/attachment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@PreAuthorize(...)
public void upload(@PathVariable User user, 
                   @RequestParam("file") List<MultipartFile> files) {
  // handle files
}
```

However, the list of the files is always empty although request contains them.

If I add the third [`MultipartRequest`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartRequest.html) parameter to the method:

```
public void upload(@PathVariable User user, 
                   @RequestParam("file") List<MultipartFile> files,
                   MultipartRequest request)
```

I can see it contains my uploaded files correctly:

[image: request contents]

What might be the reason of empty `List<MultipartFile>`?

I'm using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to submit the files, but I don't think it is connected with the issue. Spring 4.2.4.

Comment: Your config? You need a library and a matching resolver for multipart uploads.

Comment: I assumed you read the blog post you were referring to. `commons-fileupload` e.g.

Comment: Yes, I have all that set up. In fact, I can receive those files by reading them from `multipartRequest.getFileMap().values()`. What I'm asking is why I cannot simply use `List<MultipartFile>` as suggested in the sources I refer to.

Comment: Presumably something is missing. If, for instance, the standard servlet multipart support is included but you use the commons multipart resolver - as suggested in the blog post - `files` won't get populated.

Comment: Is it possible to get List<User> with List<MultipartFile> in request?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem was that [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) by default submits array of files using names `file[0]`, `file[1]` etc. It is configurable with the [`arrayKey`](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#upload-service) value when using `Upload` Service. Setting it to empty string forces the files to be sent under the same `file` key, which is correctly resolved with Spring and the `@RequestParam("file") List<MultipartFile>` contains all files that has been submitted.

```
Upload.upload({url: url, data: {file: arrayOfFiles}, arrayKey: ''})
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use  `@ModelAttribute` like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{user}/attachment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @PreAuthorize(...) 
    public void upload(@PathVariable User user,@ModelAttribute("uploadFile") FileUpload uploadFile) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {

    List<MultipartFile> files = uploadFile.getFiles();
    ...
```

And create a class like:

```
     public class FileUpload {
     private List<MultipartFile> files;
     public List<MultipartFile> getFiles() {
        return files;
     }

    public void setFiles(List<MultipartFile> files) {
       this.files= files;
      }
   }
```

Comment: But I want to upload multiple files at once.

Answer (score 3):

for multiple files. do this in your javascript

```
//first add files to form data
var formData = new FormData();
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append("images", files[i]);
}

//post files to backend e.g using angular
 $http.post('upload', formData, {
     transformRequest: angular.identity,
     headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
 })
 .then(function(response){
      console.log("UPLOAD COMPLETE::=> ", response);
 }, function (error) {
      console.log(error);
 });
```

Do this in your java

```
//your java method signature
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE )
public Response uploadImage(@RequestParam(value = "images") MultipartFile[] images){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That works for me, sending big 'email' object with multiple file attachments from UI to back-end:

Angular

```
sendEmailWithAttachments(taskId: string, template: string, email: any, modelConfig: any, files: any[]) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('form', new Blob([JSON.stringify(email)], {type: 'application/json'}));
    files.forEach(file  => {
        formData.append('files', file);
    });

    return this.$http({
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        url: this.baseUrl + '/' + taskId + '/email-with-attachment?template=' + template,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
        },
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    });
}
```

Java Spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{taskId}/email-with-attachment", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void sendEmailWithAttachment(
        @PathVariable String taskId,
        @RequestParam String template,
        @RequestParam("form") MultipartFile form,
        @RequestParam("files") List<MultipartFile> files) throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new ObjectMapper().readValue(form.getInputStream(), HashMap.class);
    
    System.out.println("taskId"+ taskId);
    System.out.println("template"+ template);
    System.out.println("files"+ files);
    System.out.println("parameters"+ parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the way you sent data from front, it can not **bound** with java.util.List. If you create a JSON data as request and you annotated your List with @RequestBody like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{user}/attachment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@PreAuthorize(...)
public void upload(@PathVariable User user, 
                   @RequestBody List<MultipartFile> files) {
  // handle files
}
```

this should work. Some info [here](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/014-post-json-to-spring-rest-webservice/).

Comment: Didn't work out-the-box for me, but I prefer the approach. Ended up using @francz method above.

Comment: The solution you propose with the @RequestBody is, in fact, correct when the body of the request has a direct translation into a domain object you have on the backend. For instance, it can be used to parse the body from JSON data to an object. However, it will not work with MultipartFile.

Comment: Will i be able to get List<User> and List<MultipartFile> ?

Comment: Not with this format of API structure, but you can make a POJO with both lists and try to work with that.