# Preservring client relative path when performing multi file upload with ng-file-upload

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, file-upload

I have a web form that I'm trying to add multi-file upload to. Currently, I can select a folder and upload multiple files. I have a Spring controller which gets the `List<MultipartFile>` containing all the files, resucively. However, the "original file name" includes JUST the file name. What I want is the relative path from the selected root folder, and the file name.

For example, if user uploads a directory C:\MyStuff\mypics\, I'd want to see "dog\dog1.jpg", "cat\cat5.jpg", etc. Or, "mypics\dog\dog1.jpg" would be acceptable.

HTML:

```
<button ngf-select="myController.uploadTest($files)"
   multiple="multiple" webkitdirectory accept="image/*">Select Files ngf</button>
```

AngularjS Controller:

```
            // for multiple files:
            myController.uploadFiles = function (files) {
                console.log("uploading files: " + files.length);
                if (files && files.length) {
                    // send them all together for HTML5 browsers:
                    Upload.upload({
                            url: 'load-service/upload-test',
                            data: {file: files, myVal1: 'aaaa'},
                            // setting arraykey here force the data to be sent as the same key
                            // and resolved as a List<> in Spring Controller.
                            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160483/empty-listmultipartfile-when-trying-to-upload-many-files-in-spring-with-ng-fil
                            arrayKey: ''
                    }).then(function (response) {
                        // log
                    }, function (response) {
                        // log
                    }, function (event) {
                        // log that file loaded
                    });
                }
            }
```

Java Spring Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value="upload-test")
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadTest(@RequestBody List<MultipartFile> file) {
    try {
        LOGGER.info("Received file set of size: " + file.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < file.size(); i++) {
            // testing, should be debug
            MultipartFile singleFile = file.get(i);
            String fileName =singleFile.getName();
            String originalFileName = singleFile.getOriginalFilename();
            LOGGER.info("Handling file: " + fileName);
            LOGGER.info("Handling file (original): " + originalFileName);
            LOGGER.info("File size: " + singleFile.getSize());
            LOGGER.info("--");
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new GeneralResponse("Handled file list of size: " + file.size()));
    }  catch (Exception ex) {
        String msg = "Error getting files";
        LOGGER.error(msg, ex);
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new GeneralResponse(msg, ex));
    }
}
```

I see that my controller is being called, but there's nothing I can see in teh MultipartFile objects that tell me the relative path of the files. When I debug in my browser, I can see that the files, prior to upload, have a field of webkitRelativePath attribute which has the relative path, but I don't see how to transfer that over to the server side in Spring.

[image]

Do I need to upload one file at a time and provide the relative path for each file as an optional argument to the call?

Comment: you want to see something like 'C:/Downloads/123.text' path from client computer?

Comment: Not exactly. If they upload a directory C:\MyStuff\mypics, I'd want to see "myPics\dog\dog1.jpg", "myPics\cat\cat5.jpg", etc. Essentially, what is in the webktiRelativePath value on the client side. Will edit question to specify.