# HTTP Error 400 "Required request part 'file' is not present" when uploading file

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, file-upload

I'm trying to make an upload utility to load an excel file and make a bulk insert into DB.

I'm using AngularJS and Spring.

I've been trying for days, but I can't get java to read the uploaded file.

I'm using `ngFileUpload` and javascript is getting my file, but when I call my Controller the param is null or whatever the http error is the 400 "Required request part 'file' is not present".

[Request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgHGm.png)

I tried everything, adding the `multipartresolver` into config; enabling the multipart encoding into application.properties; adding the library into the `pom.xml`, but it still doesn't works.

```
server.port=8081
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=15000000
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=15000000
```

---

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
     return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
}


@PostMapping(value = "/excelUploader", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<?> saveEnvironmentConfig(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile submissions){
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT**
**Client Side Part**

```
 $scope.upload = function() {

                    Upload.upload({
                        url: $scope.uploadServiceUrl,
                        data: { file: $scope.files,
                            method: 'POST'}



                    }).then(function(resp) {

                        if ($scope.uploadCompleteFn) {
                            $scope.uploadCompleteFn();
                        }

                        console.log('Upload complete.');

                    }, function(resp) {
                        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
                    });
                };
```

Comment: Please share the client-side code as well.

Comment: Did you check in your browser's network inspector if and how the file is sent?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca

Hi federico, i shared the client side code :)

Comment: Hi @lugiorgi

Yes i checked it. (I edited my questions)

Comment: Why are you *returning* `null` from your server? Have you tried actually returning something?

Comment: Check if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160483/empty-listmultipartfile-when-trying-to-upload-many-files-in-spring-with-ng-fil helps you. I know you are only uploading one file but maybe it will lead you to the right solution.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I'm returning nulla just only for test...

I'm using the debugger to check values..

Comment: @lugiorgi You saved my life...

The problem was that ng-file-upload by default submits array of files...
So If I pass:
 data: { file: $scope.files[0] }

It works.

Last question: Is there any way to pass single file? (I don't like to pass array[0])
Thank you

Comment: Glad I could save your life ;) Did you change your js Upload to contain _arrayKey: ''_ as described in the linked answer? It seems like that might enable you to just pass your array as upload param.